# Recognizing patterns in a table with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, aggregate-functions, min

I have the following table

```
ID       Date       Activity
1    10-20-2019        X
1    10-20-2019        Y
1    10-23-2019        X
1    10-23-2019        Y
1    10-25-2019        Z
2    10-10-2019        X
2    10-15-2019        X
2    10-16-2019        X
2    10-20-2020        X
3    10-12-2020        X
3    10-13-2020        X
3    10-14-2020        Y
3    10-15-2020        Y
4    10-10-2020.       Y
4    10-12-2020        Y
4    10-15-2020        Z
4    10-15-2020        Z
```

Each ID represents a unique person who performs an activity on a certain date. A person may perform multiple activities on the same date (ID 1 performs activity X and Y on the same day multiple times) and this is recorded as two separate entries in the table.

I need an SQL query that returns all the IDs of people who have ever performed a different activity from the task(s) they performed on their first day. The new activity cannot be a subset of the first activity (if ID 1 performs X and Y on one day and then just X on another, this does not count as a different activity).

I used min(date) to find the activity on their first date, but I am having trouble dealing with the case of performing multiple activities on the same day. Also my query takes about 1 min to run which is surprising given I have only 2000 records.

The query run on the table above should ideally return the following:

```
ID
1
3
4
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Sorry,  I still confused, why ID 2 filtered out from result

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev It's because they only perform activity X and nothing else, there is no different activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select id
from (
    select id, activity, min(date) min_date
    from mytable t
    group by id, activity
) t
group by id
having min(min_date) <> max(min_date)
```

The idea is to compute the minimum date per `id` *and `activity`. If a given `id` has more than one distinct minimum date, then we know an new activity appeared later on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and get the activities for each id using:

```
select t.*
from (select t.id, activity,
             min(date) as min(date) as min_activity_date,
             min(min(date)) over (partition by id) as min_date
      from t
      group by id, activity
     ) t
where min_activity_date > min_date
```

Comment: This returns the activities as well as the ids, which seems helpful to me.